# Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS request did not succeed) when sending http reqeust from angular 8 to Express.js backend docker containers

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, cors

I am running 2 docker containers, `frontend` and `backend`. The frontend is running Angular 8 on port `4200`, and the backend is running Express.js on port `8080`. Whenever I send an http request to the backend, like so:

```
getMeetings(): Observable<MeetingList> {
    // The url is http://backend:8080/backend/scheduled-meetings
    return this.http.get<MeetingList>(environment.backend + '/scheduled-meetings';);
}
```

I get this error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend:8080/backend/scheduled-meetings. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    command: npm run start
    volumes: 
      # Mount the host path, ., to the path "/usr/src/app" in the docker container.
      # Do this so that nodemon can watch for file changes and restart within the container.
      # Should move to a src folder.
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - '4200:4200' # Port mapping
    volumes:
      - './frontend:/usr/src/app'
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` for the angular container:

```
FROM node:12

# Create working directory and make it the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular && npm install

# Bundle the app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` for the Express container:

```
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

I have tried the following within the Express application:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

I have also use proxys in the Angular project by adding `"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"` to `angular.json` like so:

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "frontend:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json",
        "optimization": false
    },
...
```

and served the project using this command in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json",
    ...
}
```

Here is the `proxy.conf.json` file:

```
{
    "/backend/*": {
        "target": "http://backend:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/backend": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this error happening? I thought that adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in Node.js would fix the issue but it didn't. Now I have tried several other configurations using proxies in Angular and still getting this error.

Comment: The error may comes from http protocol. You may have a check in the `ContentType`? In my experience(I do not use express), you set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, almost all scenes will be ok——except :   `ContentType` values `application/json` , willl first send `OPTIONS` requests before the requests you want send,such as `GET`,`POST`,so, May this error?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just make it work (and I'm pretty sure that is the case) just allowing any cors request would work for you. just installing `cors` and adding

```
app.use(require('cors')());
```

will solve your problem. for more configuration and information refer to this guide https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
Angular proxy is meant for development, not for running it in production. don't use it, if you don't know what exact problems it solves